# How to Delete Negative numbers from my list in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and i have been scribbling with lists. i want to only print out the positive numbers in my list,However only the first negative element gets removed, the second negative element remains as it is.

Here's my code:

```
def myfunc(mylist1) :
    print("List before sorting the elements : ", mylist1)
    mylist1.sort()
    print("List after sorting the elements : ", mylist1)
    for i in range(0,len(mylist1)) :
        if mylist1[i] <= 0  :
            del mylist1[i]

        else:
            break
    print("After Operations,Final list : ", mylist1)
    return
mylist = [67,78,54,-20,-23,44]
myfunc(mylist)
```

Output:

```
List before sorting the elements :  [67, 78, 54, -20, -23, 44]
List after sorting the elements :  [-23, -20, 44, 54, 67, 78]
After Operations,Final list :  [-20, 44, 54, 67, 78]
```

Comment: you're deleting from a list that you are iterating over which is causing weird results

Comment: Yes, as @aws_apprentice when you delete the first element (my_list[0]), the second element becomes the first element and in the second iteration the third element (currently second element) which is positive is checked and the loop breaks.

Comment: oh! that made it quiet clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove them with list comprehension. This is how you can define the function:

```
def myfunc(mylist1):
     return sorted([x for x in mylist1 if x > 0])
print(myfunc(mylist1))
```

Comment: It worked great ! i am yet to study on list comprehensions, ill work on it right now. Thanks